# App crashes when starting GoogleMaps FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm experiencing the following problem:
when I press a button, my main activity starts a `FragmentActivity` that is meant to use Google libs to show a map centred at the coordinates passed by the first activity.
Now, I've put a few Log.i lines in the `FragmentActivity` and it seems that its `onCreate` method is called, and the crash occurs when trying to set the `ContentView` of the activity.
Here's the chunk of code where I call the `FragmentActivity`, called ShowMap:

```
mbtMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent aprimappa = new Intent(MyCoordinates.this,ShowMap.class);
            Bundle catasta = new Bundle();
            catasta.putDouble("lat", Lati);
            catasta.putDouble("lon", Longi);
            aprimappa.putExtras(catasta);
            Log.i(TAG, "Intento preparato. Chiamo ShowMap.");
            startActivity(aprimappa);
        }
    });
```

And here's the first bit of my

**ShowMap.class:**

```
public class ShowMap extends FragmentActivity{

final static String TAG="thereyouwere";

private GoogleMap googlemap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "Siamo nell'onCreate di ShowMap.");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);
    Log.i(TAG,"Caricato layout di ShowMap.");
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    double lat=b.getDouble("lat");
    double lon=b.getDouble("lon");
```

In case you need it, here are also my `AndroidManifest.XML` and the xml layout of

**ShowMap:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.paquito.thereyouwere"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<!-- Google Maps API Key -->
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="***********************" />

<permission
    android:name="it.paquito.thereyouwere.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name="it.paquito.thereyouwere.MyCoordinates"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity android:name="ShowMap"></activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Thank you in advance for any help you might give me!

Comment: Could you please add logcat?

Answer (score 0):

First Put your `Maps API` keys under `<application>` tag in `manifest.xml`

```
 ....<application>
 <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="***********************" />
 </application>
```

You might required this changes because your  `minsdkversion<12` and for the lower version(pre Honeycomb) devices used `SupportMapFragment`..

And you should use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` change

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

With

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Also change

```
 _googleMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();
```

With

```
_googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
    R.id.fragment1)).getMap();
```

and also check

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

You just need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>
```

This is because latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using `<meta-data .. />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`